# How to use hex counting in filenames for programmatic loading?

Tags: objective-c, c, hex

I have several directories of 12 .caf files and am loading them programmatically:

```
NSString *soundToPlay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sounds/%d/%d_%d.caf", type, note, timbre];
```

If I want to, say, increment from `9` to `10` in one of those values, suddenly my string is an extra character long, which makes it harder to manipulate later with something like `NSMakeRange`. I'd like to keep all these `%d`s to a single character.

What I'd like to do is name my files using the digits 0-9 but then continue with A, B, C instead of 10, 11, 12. This would keep everything single-character. I'm hoping there's an easy way to do this kind of thing, still allowing stuff like increment, +/-, and modulo. If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X` is the hexadecimal format specifier:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sounds/%X/%X_%X.caf", type, note, timbre]
```

Alternatively you could always use two digit numbers. That would allow to select from more than 16 cases:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sounds/%02d/%02d_%02d.caf", type, note, timbre]
```